# Regex for special characters in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have below country names which contains some special characters.

1. CONGO, DEM. REP. OF THE
2. COTE D’IVOIRE
3. GUINEA–BISSAU
4. KOREA, REPUBLIC OF (SOUTH)

So, I wrote a regular expression to validate that a country name that must not contain any numeric and special characters other than `,` `.` `'` `-` `(` `)`

I wrote below regex

```
string country = "COTE D’IVOIRE"
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(country.Trim(), @"^[a-zA-Z\-'()/.,\s]+$");
```

but it just not doing the thing. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The curly apostrophe, it is not in the character class.

Comment: I dont think that `'` and `’` is the same symbol

Comment: @w.b: No, dot is treated as a literal in the character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to also allow curly apostrophe, just add it to the character class:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z’\-'()/.,\s]+$"
          ^
```

Note that you do not have to escape `-` if it is at the end of the character class and you can use `(?i)` case-insensitive modifier to shorten the `a-zA-Z` part:

```
@"(?i)^[a-z’'()/.,\s-]+$"
```

C#:

```
string country = "COTE D’IVOIRE";
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(country.Trim(), @"(?i)^[a-z’'()/.,\s-]+$");
// or use RegexOptions.IgnoreCase option
//bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(country.Trim(), @"^[a-z’'()/.,\s-]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add the `’` to the list of symbols

```
string country = "COTE D’IVOIRE"
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(country.Trim(), @"^[a-zA-Z\-'’()/.,\s]+$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
^[a-zA-Z\-–'’()\/.,\s]+$
```

### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/jlI9Y3QSis)